# ng-repeat angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com um GRID e eu precisava formatar as datas vindas para esse GRID usando `data filter` do Angular.

Porém não estou conseguindo printar o array das datas dentro da tag `<div>`, se eu colocar para printar num `<tr>` ou `<td>` dá certo, mas eu já estou usando um **ng-repeat** na `<tr>`, precisaria de um outro **ng-repeat** só para uma determinada coluna.

Meu html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>C.P.F</th>
    <th>CNH</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Vencimento</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in registros | filter : filtro">
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.nome}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.cpf}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.rg}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.texto_cnh}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.datas[$index]}}</a></td>

    <tr ng-repeat = "y in data track by $index">
        <td>{{y | date : "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Minha função que retorna os registros no controller:

```
$http.get(linkservice + "select").then(function (response) {    
    $scope.registros = response.data;
    $scope.data = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.registros.length; i++){
        var data = new Date($scope.registros[i].data_nascimento);
        $scope.data.push(data);
    }
    $scope.registros.datas = $scope.data;
    console.log($scope.registros);
});
```

Comment: A data que você deseja usar em uma coluna separada, ela faz parte do objeto `registros`? Ou é uma array a parte, como mostra seu `controller`?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Então, eu tentei das duas formas, na verdade, de inicio, ela era um array separado, mas pensei em colocar cmo objeto em registros, para utilizar um único ng-repeat, mas mesmo assim, a coluna fica vazia

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara, e seria bem melhor se você pudesse mostrar um exemplo do conteúdo de `$scope.registros` e  `$scope.data`. Ainda Assim, segue um exemplo simplificado de visualização:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>C.P.F</th>
    <th>CNH</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Vencimento</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in registros | filter : filtro" ng-click="enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">
    <td>{{x.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{x.cpf}}</td>
    <td>{{x.rg}}</td>
    <td>{{x.texto_cnh}}</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat='y in x.datas'>
                <td>{{y}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```